# CSS grid layout problems

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, css-grid

So I am new to CSS grid. I have designed a layout for the web page for this example. I have labelled out how the page should be i,e cols & rows and their numbers. (image here https://postimg.cc/PPxDXKsx)

Even with this I still struggling to get CSS grid to layout correctly.

I have attached the HMTL CSS boiler plate of how my page is structured (without the content for now)

A lot of research on how CSS grid works.
Within each section I have tried to color code the background of each div so a can visualise each sections layout. As well as using Firefox dev tools the grid systems will still not go how I want it.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

        <header class= "header"> 
        <!-- Nav Bar-->
        </header>




    <div class= "container page-grid"> <!-- Main CSS grid-->

        <!-- Mini nav bar under main one-->
        <section>
        <div class="new-in-section">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">NEW IN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JACKETS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WAISTCOATS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FORMAL COATS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TROUSERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUITS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CLEARANCE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </section>  


        <!-- Main product section-->
        <section>

            <div class="mens-tweed-product">
            </div>

        </section>



        <!-- Garment care  section-->
        <section>

            <div class="garment-care-section"> 
            </div>

        </section>




          <!--Complete the outfit section  --> 
        <section>

            <div class="complete-outfit-section">
            </div>

        </section>



        <!--Recently viewed section  --> 
        <section> 

            <div class="recent-viewed-section">          
            </div>
        </section>   


    </div>   <!-- Main CSS grid-->


</body>
```

```
 <!-- Main CSS grid-->
 .page-grid {
 display: grid; 
 grid-template-columns: 1fr , repeat (2 1fr); /* Two columns  */
 grid-template-rows:  1fr, repeat (8 1fr); /* eight rows  */

 grid-gap: 25px 25px; /* Short hand for both col and row */
 grid-gap: 25px 25px; /* Short hand for both col and row */
 margin:0px;
 padding:10px; 
 }



 /* Style for "New Nav In Section" */
 .new-in-section{
width: 1250px;
height: 20px;
background-color:lightblue;
background-color:none;
grid-column-start: 1; 
grid-column-end: 1 ; 
grid-row-start:1; 
grid-row-end:1;
}


.mens-tweed-product {
    height:1180px;
    height:575px; 
    background-color:lightgreen;
    grid-column-start: 1; 
    grid-column-start: 3; 
    grid-row-start: 2; 
    grid-row-end: 4;  
    }


.garment-care-section{
width: 1180px;
height: 345px;
background-color:lightcoral;
grid-column-start: 1; 
grid-column-end: 3; 
grid-row-start: 6; 
grid-row-end: 7; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here that I can see:

#### Grid Syntax

Your syntax for the grid in `.page-grid` is wrong, and so no grid is even registering.

```
/* formerly 1fr, repeat (2 1fr) should be: */
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

I'd recommend taking another look at [MDN's CSS repeat() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) and then giving it another go.

#### Conflicting properties in a single rule

CSS will take whatever you put last if I recall. So, in `.mens-tweed-product` when you put `grid-column-start` as both `1` and `3`, browsers will render that as `grid-column-start: 3;`.

#### Grid applies only to direct children

As you have it now, only the `<section>`s are actually part of your grid. So when you try to style the `.mens-tweed-product` with `grid-column-start`, `grid-column-end`, and so forth they won't have any effect.

You might try [Nested Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#Nesting_grids) as Mozilla summarizes here. There's also an emerging `subgrid` property which will do what you want (I think), but it's not well-supported yet so you should just keep it on your radar for now.

#### Missing negative sign, maybe?

I think in the `.new-in-section` you may be trying to use the `grid-column-end: -1;` to say, "Cover the full row." Fix your sign and you'll get what you want there.

If that's *not* what you were trying, try it! And learn more about [negative grid lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid#Counting_backwards) in the docs.